# Cannot cast array data from dype ('<M8[ms]') to dtype ("float64') according to the rule safe

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate datetime data from a file called "heading" to the rate of time of a file called "posistion." When I use the interpolation code posted, I get the TypeError:  Cannot cast array data from dtype('

I used this code to convert heading (hdg)date and time to datetime

```
    hdg_t = np.zeros(np.shape(hdg_date), dtype = 'datetime64[ms]')
```

I used this code to convert it to a format numpy could read as its in milliseconds

```
    hdg_t_ms = hdg_t.astype('uint64')
```

I did the exact same for the position data then tried to interpolate heading to the rate of time in position (pos)

```
    x=hdg_t_ms
    x1=pos_t
    hdg_interp = np.interp(x1, x, hdg)
```

This code gives the TypeError